# dynamic report pivoted in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have already asked this question on [Microsoft Suport](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/889eb539-419d-4897-90f3-e0d40e0446a8/ssrs-row-and-column-grouping-sorting-order?forum=sqlreportingservices), but got no answers so far.

My report is pulling all employees for a company, their departments (on rows) and all their elected benefits on columns. For some big companies it is quite heavy(about 400,000 rows). I can pull it from the database in less then 3 minutes. But rendering this on the report takes a lot of time. I wonder how can help SSRS engine by sorting my result set properly.

Here is my row groups:

Department (parent),

Employee (child)

Then I have column groups:

Benefit Type (Medical, Dental, Vision, etc) as parent,

Benefit Selected Property (Monthly Rate, Plan Name, etc) as child

So report should look like all employees from Department A, then single row of per employee, then on columns all his benefits and user selected benefit properties.

What is my correct order by from the database to make that report run faster?

Comment: The first thing I would do is deploy the report and then check the execution logs after you run it ( `select * from ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog` ). My bet is that the render time, not the data retrieval time is the issue. If this is the case then the order you retrieve the data is irrelevant and there is not much you can do.

Comment: thanks a lot! When i increased row count 2.5 times in the report time rendering increased with the same ratio, but Time Processing increased 100 times! Data Retrieval and Byte Count stayed approximately the same

Comment: If it's processing then (I think) that is the time spent getting the output ready to render. Sometimes you can move some of the work done in SSRS expression back to the database (e.g. a complex expression to get a cell color). If you can work this out at the database end so SSRS doesn't have to do it then that will help speed things up.

Comment: problem was solved by allocating more memory to report server, thanks a lot!